# How to show dropdown data selected when bind with view model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/BrKBx1

### Model

```
public class StatesVm 
{
    public int SelectedStateId { get; set; }
    public List<State> States { get; set; }
}

public class State {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

### Controller

```
public ActionResult DropDownListForDemo()
{
    StatesVm vm = new StatesVm() { SelectedStateId = 2 };
    List<State> states = new List<State>();
    states.Add(new State() { ID = 1, Name = "West Bengal" });
    states.Add(new State() { ID = 2, Name = "Bihar" });
    states.Add(new State() { ID = 3, Name = "Orissa" });
    vm.States = states;

    return View(vm);
}
```

### View

```
@model CsMvcDemo.Models.StatesVm
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>DropDownListForDemo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedStateId, new SelectList(Model.States, "ID", "Name",2), "-- Select States--", new { id = "cboState" })
    </div>
</body>
</html>



@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedStateId, new SelectList(Model.States, "ID", "Name",3), "-- Select States--", new { id = "cboState" })
```

I want to show dropdown value selected as per my passing value. When I set value as 1 or 3 and run the code then state name should be changed but it is showing the old one.

Comment: Your code works fine in the fiddle for me. When i change the value, the dropdown selected option gets updated.

Comment: which value are you changing to 1 or 3?  it works if you change the value here `StatesVm vm = new StatesVm() { SelectedStateId = 2 };`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using a `DropDownListFor` you have to set the selected item in your model before passing it to the view. If you would like to hardcode the selected item then use the `DropDownList`

**Using a DropDownListFor**

**Change your model to**

```
public class StatesVm 
{
    public int SelectedStateId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> States
    {
        get
        {
            yield return new SelectListItem { Text = "West Bengal", Value = "1" };
            yield return new SelectListItem { Text = "Bihar", Value = "2" };
            yield return new SelectListItem { Text = "Orissa", Value = "3" };
        }
    }
}
```

**Change controller to**

```
public ActionResult DropDownListForDemo()
{
    var viewModel = new StateVm
        {
            SelectedStateId= 2
        };

        return View(viewModel);
}
```

**Your view**

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedStateId, Model.States)
```

The DropDownListFor is expecting a model value (`x=>x.SelectedStateId`) to set the selected item in your drop down list. Setting the selected item using `SelectList(Model.States, "Value", "Text", "2")` will be ignored and the SelectedStateId will be used.

To hardcode the selected value in the view you can use the DropDownList instead of DropDownListFor.

**Using a DropDownList**

```
@Html.DropDownList("cboStates", new SelectList(Model.States, "Value", "Text", "2"))
```

Comment: can't we hard code data for selection `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedStateId , new SelectList(Model.States, "Value", "Text", 1 ), new { @class = "form-control" })` i guess yes...we can give 1 or 3 and it suppose to work but in my case some time it did not work.

Comment: You have to use a DropDownList in that case. I've updated the answer.